# Permissions required for SQL Server role to be able to use OBJECT_NAME

Tags: sql-server, user-permissions

What are the minimum permission(s) and to what object(s) do I need to give to a SQL server database role to get `OBJECT_NAME` and `OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME` to return a value rather than a `NULL`?

If there's something weird then I could just use the `sys.objects` and `sys.schemas` but I assumed that using `OBJECT_NAME` and `OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME` would be the better approach for single value `@@PROCID` access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the MSDN pages for both [`OBJECT_NAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186301.aspx) and [`OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326599.aspx):

> Requires ANY permission on the object. To specify a database ID, CONNECT permission to the database is also required, or the guest account must be enabled.

So the answer is you need **any** permission on the object which you are passing to the function. Make sure you are definitely passing a valid `object_id` (which is of type `INT` and should correspond to an `object_id` value for an object in the current or specified database) when you call your function.

Comment: Granting ViewDefinition to the calling proc that is in a different user context to where the call is being made has done the trick. It's not ideal as it slightly exposes more detail than we had envisaged. However no other permissions are needed. We've also modified our handler so that if it gets a NULL value back from the OBJECT_NAME it'll return the ObjectID that was passed to it so that we can at least go and look it up manually.

Comment: Great, glad you found a solution. If my answer was helpful, please feel free to mark it as accepted.